# Diameter of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis

I've begun reading Stein's Complex Analysis book and found this in a proof of Goursat's theorem for a triangle. It mentions the 'diameter of a triangle' without explaining what is meant by that? Is it the diameter of the inscribed circle, or perhaps the superscribed circle? Or something else entirely? In case you're wondering, Figure 1 doesn't show this diameter.

[image: The offending picture]

Comment: The diameter of any set $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ is defined as $\sup\limits_{x,y\in A}|x-y|$.

Comment: I see. Wouldn't this just be the length of the longest side in the case of a triangle?

Comment: It would. ${}{}$

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/459372) for a formal proof that the diameter of a triangle is its longest side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The diameter of any nonempty subset of $\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R^n$, or of a metric space...) is $\operatorname{diam}A=\sup_{x,y\in A}|x-y|$, as njguliyev said. Opinions may vary on what the diameter of empty set should be.

It is interesting to compare $\operatorname{diam}A$ with the diameter of the smallest disk $C$ containing $A$, where $A$ is a planar set.  Clearly, $$\operatorname{diam}A\le \operatorname{diam}C$$ with equality attained when $A$ contains a pair of opposite points of $C$. In the converse direction, the following is true (but is not straightforward to prove): 
$$\operatorname{diam}C\le \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\operatorname{diam}A$$
Equality holds when $A$ is an equilateral triangle.

It should be noted that when $A$ is a triangle, $C$ does not always coincide with the superscribed circle.