# Looking for a proof that the diameter of the smallest bounding circle is less than or equal to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ times the diameter of the set

Tags: geometry, reference-request, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

This came up while I was attempting to solve an old journal problem. It's not the easiest result to search for so I figured I would ask.

Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the diameter of $E$ is

$$\operatorname{diam} E = \sup \{d(p,q) \mid p,q \in E\}$$

where $d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. As [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/539668/118815) states, the diameter of $C$, the smallest disc capable of covering $E$, is less than or equal to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \operatorname{diam} E$. The answer also claims that this inequality is "not straightforward to prove." Where can I find a proof of this?

Comment: You mean $ p,q\in E$ in the definition of diam.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung%27s_theorem

Comment: http://cstheory.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/jungs-theorem/

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, thank you, I've corrected that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you for the links and the name of the theorem!

Comment: @Benjamin: you're welcome.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @augurar: just done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jung's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung%27s_theorem) states that if $K$ is a compact subset of $R^n$ and 
$$ d=\max_{p,q\in K}\|p-q\|_2, $$
there exist a closed ball with radius
$$ r\leq d\sqrt{\frac{n}{2(n+1)}}$$
that contains $K$, and the equality is achieved only by the regular $n$-simplex.

The [proof](http://cstheory.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/jungs-theorem/) relies on a convexity argument and the use of [Helly's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem).

Comment: I guess more precisely, equality is achieved for any $K$ whose _convex hull_ is the regular $n$-simplex.

Comment: Agreed.$\phantom{}$

Answer (score 2):

Assume without loss of generality that $E$ is compact. Consider the *smallest* circumscribed circle $C$ of $E$. To fix ideas, assume that $C$ has unit radius (the problem is scale-invariant).

Form the intersection $T=C\cap E$. Then $T$ has the property that it is not contained in any semicircle of $C$ (otherwise by first variation $C$ would not be the smallest circle).

Either $T$ consists of a pair of opposite points of $C$, in which case the result is immediate, or one can choose three points $P,Q,R\in T$ such that the set $\{P,Q,R\}$ does not lie in any semicircle of $C$. The shortest arcs then satisfy $$PQ+QR+RP=2\pi.$$ Therefore one of the three arcs is at least $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. This is equivalent to the answer you want.